# Async requests to model-bound action methods with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have an ASP.NET MVC action method which uses model binding to accept a strongly typed model object as its input, i.e:

```
public PartialViewResult SaveUser([Bind(Prefix = "User")]User NewUser)
{
}
```

How do I specify the argument when requesting this method asynchronously with JQuery? I have previously used the load() or post() methods to make asynchronous requests, but this was with only one or two named parameters. How do I pass the entire form data with async requests to this method?

This is one approach I have tried:

```
$.post('/Users/SaveUser/', { NewUser: $('#theForm') }, function(responseText, status) {
    $('#mainContent').text(responseText);
}, 'html');
```

I added a breakpoint in the action method and the NewUser parameter is null.

Am I completely off with this approach? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mapping between the input names and their values.  The model binder will be expecting to see:

```
User.Name=username
User.FirstName=Bill
User.LastName=Gates
...
```

as the form parameters on the request.  Try using the [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) method.

```
$('form').serialize()
```

to construct your parameters for the AJAX call.

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you! I never knew about the serialize method.